# How do you automate integration testing between an Android app and a Rails application

Tags: java, android, ruby-on-rails, rspec, junit

I am writing an android application that interacts with a Rails app via json.

I rails I build tests with rspec. Language is ruby.

Android I have been testing in junit.  Language is java.

For simplicity lets say that the ruby app produces an object called Message that has an ID, and Data when you hit myapp.com/messages

On the android side, when the app runs it hits the webservice and parses that json and builds that message object.

The final product expected would be some sort of automated test that asserts that when a message is created on the rails app the android app has that object.

I know this is an integration test so I am not expecting this to be fast (though that would be nice).  Instead I am looking for how to approach this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For Automated Testing of an application please find UI automator tools in Android.